# Extend component with baseprops in Vuejs3

Tags: vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I try to extend a component with some baseprops from another file. But I didn't get it work

```js
//selectable.js
export function selectable() {
  const props = {
    label: {
      type: String,
      default: 'sdg',
    },
  }

  const isSelected = ref(false)

  function toggleSelection() {
    isSelected.value = !isSelected.value
  }

  return {
    baseProps: props,
    isSelected,
    toggleSelection
  };
}
```

```js
//checkbox.vue
<!-- components/YourComponent.vue -->
<template>
    <div class="flex cursor-pointer" @click="toggleSelection">
      <input type="checkbox" :checked="isSelected">
      <label>
        <slot>{{ label }}</slot>
      </label>
    </div>
  </template>
  
  <script setup>
  import { selectable } from '~/components/primitives/_selectable'
  
  const { baseProps, isSelected, toggleSelection } = selectable()

  const props = defineProps({
    ...baseProps,
    moreProps: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0,
    }
  })

  </script>
```

I get only this warning, but do not know how to resolve it...

```
[@vue/compiler-sfc] `defineProps()` in <script setup> cannot reference locally declared 
variables because it will be hoisted outside of the setup() function. If your component 
options require initialization in the module scope, use a separate normal <script> to 
export the options instead.
/components/primitives/checkbox.vue
15 |  
16 |    const props = defineProps({
17 |      ...baseProps,
   |         ^^^^^^^^^
18 |      index: {
19 |        type: Number,
```

Answer (score 0):

ok i'm one step further, at least i think so ;) I can do this with options api instead of composition api, is this the only way to extend props?

```
  <template>
    <div>
      <input 
        :id="value"
        :value="value"
        type="checkbox"
        :checked="isSelected"
        @change="toggleSelection"
      >
      <label :for="value">
        <slot>{{ label }}</slot>
      </label>
    </div>
  </template>
  
  <script>
    import { selectable } from '~/components/primitives/_selectable'
    const { baseProps, isSelected, toggleSelection } = selectable()
    export default {
        props: {
            ...baseProps,
            moreProps: {
                type: Number,
                default: 0,
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            console.log(this.label, this.moreProps)
        },
                
        setup(props) {
            console.log(props.label, props.moreProps)
            return {
                isSelected,
                toggleSelection
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```